# How can I get a list of all the named ranges from a workbook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying, with Excel VBA, to look at all named ranges and charts from one workbook and paste it into a PowerPoint presentation.

I run `UpdateDropdownColumn()` to create a dropdown of all the objects in the Excel workbook (charts, list tables and ranges). I have separate code that will run through each of these objects, find it in Excel and copy the selected object into the PowerPoint presentation. This part appears to be working.

`UpdateDropdownColumn` works for selecting all charts and list tables but not for selecting all range names within a workbook.

Here is the code for the first piece:

```vb
Sub UpdateDropdownColumn()
    
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlTable As ListObject
    Dim xlTableColumn As ListColumn
    Dim xlChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim xlTableObject As ListObject
    Dim xlRangeObject As Range
    
    Dim ObjectArray() As String
    Dim ObjectArrayIndex As Integer
    
    'set the book
    Set xlBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Loop through each worksheet
    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
    
        'If we have charts
        If xlSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        
            'Grab each Chart Name
            For Each xlChartObject In xlSheet.ChartObjects
            
                'Update the count
                ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
                
                'add the chart object to the array
                ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = xlChartObject.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(xlChartObject) 'can make the delimiter @@ if '_' is used
            
            Next
        End If
        
        'If we have tables
        If xlSheet.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        
            'Grab each ListTable Name
            For Each xlTableObject In xlSheet.ListObjects
            
                'Update the count
                ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
                
                'add the list table object to the array
                ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = xlTableObject.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(xlTableObject)
            
            Next
        End If
        
        ''*** Set ExcTbl = Worksheets("G.W").Range("Print_Area1")
        
        'If we have range names
        If xlSheet.Names.Count > 0 Then
        
            'Grab each Range Name
            For Each xlRangeObject In xlSheet.Names.RefersToRange
            'xlSheet.Names.Item
            
                'Update the count
                ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
                
                'add the range object to the array
                ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = xlRangeObject.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(xlRangeObject)
            
            Next
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Grab the sheet
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Export")
    
    'grab the table from the sheet
    Set xlTable = xlSheet.ListObjects("ExportToPowerPoint") 'this is the table name
    
    'grab the object column from my table
    Set xlTableColumn = xlTable.ListColumns("object")
    
    'set the validation dropdown
    With xlTableColumn.DataBodyRange.Validation
    
        'delete the old one
        .Delete
        
        'add the new data to the dropdown
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(ObjectArray, ",")
        
        'make sure it's a dropdown
        .InCellDropdown = True
        
    End With

End Sub
```

How can I get all the named ranges from a particular worksheet into my dropbox?

Comment: Do you make it into your `if` statement. Can you add a breakpoint on `If xlSheet.Names.Count > 0` and hover `xlSheet.Names.Count` and see if it's greater than 0? If it is, I see no reason why this code wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. I do seem to get a value on the statement  If xlSheet.Names.Count > 0    But then it doesn't work when it gets to the following line
            For Each xlRangeObject In xlSheet.Names.RefersToRange   <<-- this seems to be the problem area but I do not know how to fix it....Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Oh right. Yeah.. .that won't work. Instead `For Each namedRange in xlSheet.Names` is the right way to go. Then `objectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = namedRange.name & " - " & xlSheet.name & "-" & TypeName(namedRange.xlRangeObject)`. Not sure on that list `TypeName()` deal, but you can futz with that to get whatever you are wanting out of it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is also named ranges that exist at the workbook level too. `For Each namedRange in ThisWorkbook.Names` may give you a different list. Don't quote me on that though, it's been at least a few years since I monkeyed with named ranges in the vba model.

Comment: My colleague Jan Karel Pieterse has a Name Manager add-in that manages all aspects of Names in Excel, much better than Excel's own Name Manager. It's free, and you can get it here: [Name Manager: Range Names Made Easy](https://jkp-ads.com/excel-name-manager.asp). One of the features is exporting a list of Names and their properties to a new worksheet.

Comment: that worked. Thank you very much @JNevill. Now I seem to have an issue with the copying functionality. For some reason the copying function is not working properly. Any suggestions on this....

Comment: In fact I might post that as a separate issue as the code is too long to put in the comments

Comment: I will try and put a link to this thread